# Sansevieria "Moonshine" always reverting to S. Trifasciata?

Tags: cultivar

My Sansevieria Moonshine cultivar grows well but the plant reverts to its original striped appearance, more resembling the S. Trifasciata than the original moonshine. The original moonshine coloration remains as a faint background. How do I keep the original moonshine coloration? Change lighting? fertilizer?

Comment: hi there, pictures always help

Answer (score 2):

Sansevieria Moonshine is battleship grey in its juvenile form, mostly, and less variegated.

[image: Young Moonshine]

It's not reverting to the standard form. The leaves remain broader and shorter (about a foot) than that old standby of laundry fame. So, its size makes it suitable for a window and desk plant.

[image: Older Moonshine]

Leave it crowded, and water as often or rarely as you like.
A rainforest plant, it can be treated like a desert plant if you're stingy with water.

---

To answer the core question of **keeping the plant grey**, cut off the old dark leaves. Reroot for grey growth. As the new growth shows up and looks ready for potting on its own, repeat by cutting and rerooting the dark leaf.